# jquery datepicker: weird documentation substraction in minDate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I've just read [the official docs for jQuery's datepicker, in particular the minDate setting](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate), which has this code snippet:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
    minDate: new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 1)
});
```

Can somebody explain to me what's the point of the `1 - 1` above? As far as I understand, that will be evaluated in JavaScript as a zero, which doesn't make sense for a Month in a date.

Thanks

PS: This doesn't look like a typo, because the same thing is repeated some lines after.

Answer (score 1):

Month starts with 0 so if you wants to set date as *1st Jan 2007* the you have to use

```
new Date(2007, 0, 1)
```

Which is equivalent to

```
new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 1)
```

Read [**Docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

> month: Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December.

Comment: omg, thanks! it turns out that this is different from .NET! (which starts in 1). However, I still don't see the point of using `1 - 1` instead of `0` in the documentation?